# C#: Assign array to another array: copy or pointer exchange?

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading

Sorry for asking this question, I have been Googling a bit but it seems what comes up is references to clone or copy methods, not an actual answer for my question in `C#`.

I have two arrays of bytes, and they are being accessed by two threads.

```
private byte[] buffer1 = new byte[size];
private byte[] buffer2 = new byte[size];
```

My goal is to write in `buffer1` in `Thread1`, grab a mutex, switch the pointers around and repeat the process. `Thread2` would grab a mutex and always read `buffer2`.

The goal is that `Thread2` runs fast and is not affected by the copy taking place in `Thread1`.

I am very unclear what happens when I do the following:

```
byte[] temp = buffer1;
buffer1 = buffer2;
buffer2 = temp;
```

Are the pointers being switched or is the content of `buffer2` being copied to `buffer1`? It should be a simple question but I can't seem to find the solution. `Thread1` is doing a `Marshal.Copy()`, and I don't want the call to impact `Thread2`.

Comment: Have you tried doing some tests to see what happens? :)

Comment: In your snippet of code `buffer1` and `buffer2` end up referencing to the same array. I assume you meant to use `temp` somewhere in a classic swap.

Comment: Editing it right away, thanks :) I mis-copied that one.

Comment: Look into `Buffer.BlockCopy()` also

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assignment always just copies the value of one expression into a variable (or calls a property/indexer setter).

In your case, with this:

```
buffer1 = buffer2;
```

... the value of `buffer2` is just a *reference* to a byte array. So after that assignment (and assuming no other assignments), changed made to the byte array "via" one variable will be visible "via" the other variable.

This isn't specific to array types - this is how reference types work all the way through .NET:

```
StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder y = x;
x.Append("Foo");
Console.WriteLine(y); // Foo
```

It's just a matter of understanding that arrays are always reference types.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! That's really what I wanted to know, thank you!

Answer (score 11):

The `Array` clas is [a reference type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/490f96s2.aspx), so there is no copy, only reference assign. Use the [`Array.CopyTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06x742cw.aspx) method to copy contents of one array to another.

This behaviour is a difference with `C++`, where you can override the `=` operator. In `.NET`, you can't override it, and no way to copy contents of some collection on the assign happen.

Other thing, the `reference assign` you want to do is an atomic operation, so you can consider to use the `lock-free` algorithm in your code for this part of code.